# No cpufreq sub-directory in one of the nodes in our cluster

Tags: linux, electrical-power, cpu-usage

How do you change the governor from Ondemand to something else ?

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate `cpufreq` module probably isn't loaded into that machine.  Compare the output of `lsmod` on the broken machine against a similar machine where cpufreq is working to see what module(s) you need to load for your system.

Answer (score 0):

Check with `modprobe -l` which module you can load.

Check in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor` which governor is running.

If you want to change the governor, load the module and change the sys file:

```
echo "governor" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```